# Nvidia NVML Driver/library version mismatch

Tags: cuda, driver, gpu, nvidia

When I run `nvidia-smi`, I get the following message:

> Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

An hour ago I received the same message and uninstalled my CUDA library and I was able to run `nvidia-smi`, getting the following result:

[image: nvidia-smi-result]

After this I downloaded `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb` from [the official NVIDIA page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and then simply:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

Now I have CUDA installed, but I get the mentioned mismatch error.

---

Some potentially useful information:

Running `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` I get:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  378.13  Tue Feb  7 20:10:06 PST 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

The kernel release is 4.4.0-66-generic.

Comment: You have probably mixed a previous runfile install with your (current) package manager install (apt-get).  Follow the instructions in the [cuda linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation) to remove all previous NVIDIA driver and CUDA files, and then reinstall after you have cleaned that up.  Before starting your reinstall, you may want to read the entire linux install guide doc I linked.  The conflict almost certainly arises out of your attempt to install the CUDA 8 GA2 package on top of your existing 378.13 driver install.

Comment: @talonmies Where would be a good place to ask GPU related questions, if not on Stackoverflow?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I think error occurs after Nvidia driver is updated on Linux. Maybe auto-remove and reboot is required after updating Nvidia driver.

Comment: Running `sudo reboot` solved this problem for me.

Comment: sudo reboot worked for me

Comment: sudo reboot worked for me as well. Thanks to @mikey and shivam.

Comment: Another overzealous set of 'close' votes on a question similar in nature to thousands of others that aren't closed, for a question directly relevant to the lives of thousands of programmers, that has nothing to do with 'opinion about frameworks' and everything to do with an actual developer issue, by people who probably don't spend much time actually working with either NVidia or CUDA. Again, the single greatest failing of SO is not to scale up the difficulty of closing a question at the same time as the number of close-voters scales up.

Comment: One important thing many folks are missing here is to make sure you also clean up any junk that dkms might build automatically. Make sure you clear out /var/lib/dkms/nvidia of any old module sources!

Comment: This happened to me, automatic updates broke my NVidia driver. Kinda pissed me off, so I did: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades` and choose No. Then search for multiple driver versions with `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` - e.g. I had versions 510 and 535 of various packages. Use apt-get to purge packages with the wrong version. Finally, with your correct version in hand (e.g. 535), re-install to ensure everything is rebuilt: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-modules-$(uname -r) linux-modules-nvidia-535-$(uname -r) nvidia-driver-535` Reboot and you're done.

Answer (score 788, accepted):

Surprise surprise, rebooting solved the issue (I thought I had already tried that).

The solution [Robert Crovella mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch#comment73133147_43022843) in the comments may also be useful to someone else, since it's pretty similar to what I did to solve the issue the first time I had it.

Comment: I was sceptical about this working after a reboot, but nonetheless I gave it a try, and IT WORKED!! Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekPotnis If you're wondering why reboot worked, it may be because of this: checking `/var/log/apt/history.log` on Ubuntu revealed that the system has automatically updated libcuda, which presumably required a restart to continue functioning correctly. I've since disabled those updates in the hopes that I won't see it again.

Comment: @john had same problem, reboot worked, and verified that in fact there was an automatic update, as recorded in the file you mention. thanks! would you mind sharing how to disable such updates? also, it might make sense to add this info to the current answer or a new answer.

Comment: had same problem, reboot worked! but I can't find ``/var/log/apt/history.log``. I'm using centOS, where is this file?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a permanent solution. The problem might reappear. The solution is to install an newer version of the nvidia package (`nvidia-390`). See my answer below

Comment: Wanted to add this worked for me on NVIDIA-SMI 418.39, Driver Version: 418.39,      CUDA Version: 10.1 (though we load cuda 10 libraries for TF). We will eventually need to upgrade this driver/fw combo to the latest once Tensorflow can support cuda 10.1 properly, but for now rebooting definitely still works.

Comment: This also worked for me. Some instructions include `sudo reboot now` and others don't.

Comment: I rebooted and it upgraded cuda from 10.1 to 10.2 also with Ubuntu 18 my Intel graphics card is non functional.

Comment: Cool! I had the same problem, I think related to nvidia driver auto update.

Comment: A reboot is an unnecessary drastic measure. You just need to unload the old nvidia kernel module (and it's dependencies): `sudo rmmod nvidia_drm nvidia_uvm nvidia_modeset nvidia`. See answer by [Comzyh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319156/7558731).

Comment: Don't do this! I can't log into GUI anymore after reboot!

Comment: Just restart, it works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1 & NVIDIA-SMI 450.66 & CUDA Version: 11.0 & nvidia-driver-450

Comment: Can testify too, nvidia-440.100 driver and CUDA-10.1 in /usr/local/cuda

Comment: this doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04 lts with nvidia-460 driver

Comment: Restart can temporarily solve the problem, but it will appear again in my machine

Comment: For a *permanent* solution, see my answer below. Basically you need to disable the autoupdate of the `nvidia` packages.

Comment: I ran into this problem after `apt upgrade` and a reboot as described here fixed the issue.

Comment: Same for me. Rebooting solved the problem.

Comment: It's August, 2022, and, yes, rebooting solved my problem.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, simple ```sudo update```,  ```sudo full-upgrade```, and restart solve the issue. None of the other solutions work as intended.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-es/000133480/uefi-and-secure-boot-faqs#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Tap%20F2%20or,Boot%20item%20to%20%22Disabled%22.

Comment: I don't know why. But this worked for me.

Comment: In my case (archlinux), this issue appeared after updating `nvidia-open` and `nvidia-utils`. I had to run `nvidia-modprobe` and also enable nvidia resume service with `systemctl enable --now nvidia-resume.service`. After running these and rebooting, my installation went back to normal.

Comment: Rebooting works but can't install `nvtop`

Answer (score 490):

As [etal said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/43023000#43023000), rebooting can solve this problem, but I think a procedure without rebooting will help.

For Chinese, check my blog -> [中文版](https://comzyh.com/blog/archives/967/)

The error message

> NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

tell us the Nvidia driver kernel module (kmod) have a wrong version, so we should unload this driver, and then load the correct version of kmod

### How can we do that?

First, we should know which drivers are loaded.

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

You may get

```
nvidia_uvm            634880  8
nvidia_drm             53248  0
nvidia_modeset        790528  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              12312576  86 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
```

Our final goal is to unload `nvidia` mod, so we should unload the module depend on `nvidia`:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
```

Then, unload `nvidia`

```
sudo rmmod nvidia
```

### Troubleshooting

If you get an error like `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use`, which indicates that the kernel module is in use, you should kill the process that using the kmod:

```
sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*
```

and then kill those process, then continue to unload the kmods.

### Test

Confirm you successfully unload those kmods

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

You should get nothing. Then confirm you can load the correct driver:

```
nvidia-smi
```

You should get the correct output.

Comment: @suraj it's not just linked. the answer is well written. the only issue is he didn't disclosed his affiliation and you did it.

Comment: This really works. The question is, if the wrong stuff is loaded at first, why does nvidia-smi load the correct ones after that? I mean, how does it know which are the correct ones?

Comment: @KiralyCraft The wrong one is no longer exists on disk, but still in memory. nvidia-smi just trigger a new loading procedure I think.

Comment: Brilliant! Had no idea this was what caused the problem. So rebooting does the same thing?

Comment: @alys Obviously, rebooting will unload and then reload all the module.

Comment: worked but rebooting brings the problem back .. and my resolution is not right as well. It's not a clean installation at all..

Comment: Not worked for me. 
`sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo rmmod nvidia`

`lsmod | grep nvidia` gives empty output

but there is still same error:

`nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`

After error `lsmod | grep nvidia` gives same output as at start.

Comment: It didn't work for me either, even after `sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*` I got `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use`

Comment: This solution works like a charm when there is no graphical interface used in parallel, il there is, then you need to reboot, otherwise graphical sessions will block and fail.

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora 33 after a reboot didn't solve the issue.

Comment: After `rmmod` I expect that you should `modprobe` to get those modules back. Otherwise the drivers are not loaded. But as i know there is no easy way to do so with `nvidia`. `rmmod` resulted in all `nvidia` drivers uninstalled and i had to reinstall them. I would expect a reboot to fix the problem and change apt repo to avoid automatic update - this seems like the most plausible solution to me.

Comment: Great answer, worked fine for me. Thank you very much. However, do you know what could be the root cause of that error?

Comment: This worked for me and avoided a disruptive reboot. I shut down the X server with `sudo init 3` in order to get around the `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use` problem which is a nice option if you're working remotely.

Comment: It happens to my servers occasionally, but I can't reboot my production machines. I used this instructions (rmmod), but I had to kill all processes using nvidia drivers (lsof and kill), then reload all drivers (modprobe), then restart gdm3 and gdm services (Ubuntu 20.04). It finally worked. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason which I haven't understood yet this didn't work for me. First, I stopped my display-manager from using nvidia, then I rmmod the modules and finally when I tried to modprobe back the modules I got `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia_drm not found in directory /lib/modules/`

Comment: Worked for me with my server device (Ubuntu 16.04). Thank you.

Comment: Unloading previous and loading new module after install worked.

Comment: When I try to do `sudo rmmod nvidia_drm` I get `rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'nvidia_drm': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module nvidia_drm: Operation not permitted
`

Comment: Simply rebooting did not solve my issue, but this answer did. Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me: 
`$ sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia_drm is in use`.  Check for which process: `sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*`: Empty output, i.e. nothing listed.
`$ sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'nvidia_uvm': Operation not permitted`.  What *did* work was to go back to look at the last time new nvidia drivers were installed and uninstall them, e.g. `sudo apt remove libnvidia-compute-418 libnvidia-compute-430 libnvidia-compute-520`.  Boom. Fixed instantly, without reboot.

Comment: Answer is not full, got `sudo rmmod nvidia` `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use by: nv_peer_mem`

Comment: Well, this crashed my box, but hey, that means I rebooted so...

Comment: Docker containers that are using nvidia will *not* appear in this list.  I was unable to remove the nvidia module without stopping those containers.

Comment: As of November 2023, a simple reboot worked.

Answer (score 50):

Why does the version mismatch happen and how can we prevent it from happening again?

You may find that the `versions` are different in these locations:

1. `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` (look at `nvidia-utils-xxx` package
   version). This version is reported by `NVML` and is showed by running `nvidia-smi`.
2. `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` (look at the version of Kernel
   Module,  `535.146` - for example). This version is read directly from the `proc` filesystem, populated by the NVIDIA driver.

The restart should work, but you may want to forbid the automatic update of this package by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` files.
In my experience, the best way is to simply [hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) the packages to prevent them from automatic updates by executing the commands below

```
sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-dkms-version_number
sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-driver-version_number
sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-utils-version_number
```

The `version_number` here, for example, is `535`. Replace it with your desired version.

P.S.: Some content was inspired by [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/29283744928/) (the original instruction was in Chinese, so I referenced the translated version instead)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I still don't get why it happens though. I start from a state where everything works, I don't update any package and still get the error after a seemingly random amount of time. Would you happen to know what exactly causes the mismatch to happen?

Comment: @ClonedOne let’s assume that you didn’t update your packages. Have you used the commands (1 and 2) above to check if the versions are the same? If they are not the same then obviously one or both of them got updated somehow. And  that you can try my solution (apt mark hold) or create  new question with more detail if mine doesn’t help.

Comment: @Antonio that's a correct way to do, please make sure to `mark` the version you want to use to avoid automatic update, and `unmark` it when needed. Thanks for a very informative reference. I learned a thing or two!

Comment: @Long I just realized I forgot a "not" in my comment, so I am republishing it here:
Thank you, for me what worked was running `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` and purge all the packages that were _not_ from the newer versions of the driver. Some useful links askubuntu.com/questions/18804/… askubuntu.com/questions/151941/…)

Comment: @Antonio I see, in fact removing both older and newer packages should make it work with the right version, you can double check that the currently remaining package version would match the one in `/proc/driver/nvidia/version`. Please note that in the future your package may get auto updated and that's when `hold` command comes in handy. The [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941) you copied above seems to be broken. For embedded link in comment, check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291214/). Have a good day!

Comment: @Long Yep, I killed the links while copy-pasting :/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean

Comment: Thankyou so much. I was able to fix it. i accidentally installed a different version of nvidia-utils-xxx. It helped me fix my problem.

Answer (score 40):

I was having this problem, and none of the other remedies worked. The error message was opaque, but checking the output of *[dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg)* was the key:

```
[   10.118255] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 410.79, but
           NVRM: this kernel module has the version 384.130.  Please
           NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
           NVRM: components have the same version.
```

However, I had completely removed the 384 version, and removed any remaining kernel drivers `nvidia-384*`. But even after reboot, I was still getting this. Seeing this meant that the kernel was still compiled to reference 384, but it was only finding 410. So I recompiled my kernel:

```
uname -a # Find the kernel it's using

Linux blah 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


update-initramfs -c -k 4.13.0-43-generic # Recompile it
reboot
```

And then it worked.

After removing 384, I still had 384 files in:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-XXX/XXX.YY/4.13.0-43-generic/x86_64/module
/lib/modules/4.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers

I recommend using the `locate` command (not installed by default) rather than searching the filesystem every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a good idea to use `locate nvidia-smi`. I used the command figuring out that another driver was installed.

Comment: sudo update-initramfs -c -k `uname -r` Not helped me.

Comment: `dmesg` output: `NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 418.67, but
               NVRM: this kernel module has the version 430.26.  Please
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: components have the same version.`

Comment: If `nvidia-smi` is showing *Failed to initialize NVML* despite successfully installing nvidia drivers and CUDA toolkit, issue could be that an older (and compressed) kernel with older Nvidia modules loaded at the reboot instead of an kernel with updated nvidia modules. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672261/1243763 has more clarity to this issue and resolved issue for me (Cent OS 7, nvidia/460.32.03, 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 with CUDA 11.2)

Comment: Also worth looking into [this post by Andrew Laidlaw](https://andrewlaidlawpower.medium.com/troubleshooting-nvidia-gpu-driver-issues-624ecff9852b) on correctly building kernel-specific nvidia modules.

Answer (score 36):

The top-2 answers can't solve my problem. I found a solution at the Nvidia official forum solved my problem.

The below error information may be caused by installing two different versions of the driver by different approaches. For example, install Nvidia driver by [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) and the official installer.

> Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

To solve this problem, there is only a need to execute one of the following two commands.

```sh
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
```

```sh
sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
```

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall: No such file or directory

Comment: It works. Sometimes the uninstall file does not exist.

Comment: I did this and now i dont have any nvidia drivers installed on my computer. have to reinstall again

Comment: I can see how removing one of the conflicting versions can help, but the suggested solution as it stands looks carelessly destructive. I tried it anyway, but neither would even run. I recommend not following this answer.

Comment: ok but then what? Do we need to install something or what?

Comment: it worked. after uninstalling , i installed it again from additional drivers

Comment: can you add the command to install after this

Answer (score 20):

I had the issue too (I'm running [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)).

What I did:

`dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`

Then
`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-381` (and every duplicate version, in my case I had 381, 384 and 387)

Then `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to list what's available.

And I choose `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430`.

After that, `nvidia-smi` gave the correct output (no need to reboot). But I suppose you can reboot when in doubt.

I also followed [this installation](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73#file-cuda_installation_on_ubuntu_18-04-L60) to reinstall cuda+cudnn.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked down (-1). I incremented it to 0. The command "dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia" is valid and shows what is not deleted.

Comment: I particularly liked selective purging and then listing of available drivers.

Answer (score 16):

Reboot.

If the problem still exist:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia
nvidia-smi
```

For [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) and [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) (RHEL):

```
cd /boot
mv initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak
dracut -vf initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

Then

```
reboot
```

For [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29):

```sh
update-initramfs -u
```

If the problem persists:

```sh
apt install -y dkms && dkms install -m nvidia -v 440.82
```

Change 440.82 to your actual version.

Tip: get the Nvidia driver version:

```sh
ls /usr/src
```

You will find the Nvidia driver directory, such as `nvidia-440.82`.

---

Also, you can remove all Nvidia packages and reinstall the driver again:

```sh
apt purge nvidia*
apt purge *cuda*

# Check
apt list -i |grep nvidia
apt list -i |grep cuda
```

Comment: This worked for me on Centos. Do I know why? No.

Comment: I tried this for Centos too! It worked, no idea what it did though.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly reboot would fix the issue on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver).

The “Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch?” error generally means the CUDA Driver is still running an older release that is incompatible with the CUDA toolkit version currently in use. Rebooting the compute nodes will generally resolve this issue.

Comment: it works with ubuntu 20.0.4, nvidia-driver-470 installed

Comment: reboot worked for me. Strange that linux needs reboots, thought it was a 'windows' thing.

Comment: @NathanB even human needs reboots sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

This also happened to me on Ubuntu 16.04 using the `nvidia-348` package (latest Nvidia version on Ubuntu 16.04).

However I could resolve the problem by installing `nvidia-390` through the [Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial).

So a solution to the described problem on Ubuntu 16.04 is doing this:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`

**Note:** This guide assumes a clean Ubuntu install. If you have previous drivers installed a reboot might be needed to reload all the kernel modules.

Comment: This and a restart did it for me!

Answer (score 5):

These answers did not work for me:

- [etal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/43023000#43023000)
- [Comzyh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/45319156#45319156)
- [user9170's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/54349675#54349675)

`dmesg`

```
NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 418.67, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 430.26.  Please
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Uninstall old driver `418.67` and install new driver `430.26` (download `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26.run`):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.26.run
[ignore abort]
```

`cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:40:52 CDT 2019
GCC version:  gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

Comment: The `sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall` part was crucial for me. Nothing else worked!

Comment: Had similar issue, and these commands helped fixing it after a reboot before re'installing.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work for me by rebooting or unloading the driver.
I solved the problem by updating my Nvidia driver *440.33.01* to *450.80.2*.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450

sudo reboot
```

I'm running [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) LTS (Focal Fossa), which is a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem after a normal kernel update on a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) machine. Since all CUDA and Nvidia drivers and libraries have been installed via [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)) repositories, I managed to solve the issues using the following steps:

```
sudo yum remove nvidia-driver-*
sudo reboot
sudo yum install nvidia-driver-cuda nvidia-modprobe
sudo modprobe nvidia # Or just reboot
```

It made sure my kernel and my Nvidia driver were consistent. I reckon that just rebooting may result in the wrong version of the kernel module being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have to restart my kernels and remove all the packages that I have installed previously (during the first installation). Please make sure to delete all the packages, even after removing packages by the command below:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
```

The packages, like "libtinfo6:i386", don't get removed.

I'm using [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) and Nvidia-driver-440. For that, you have to remove all the packages shown in the below image.

List of all the packages that need to be remove:

[image: img]

As shown in the image, make sure that the package you're installing is of the correct size. That is 207  MB for Nvidia-driver-440. If it's less, it means you haven't removed all the packages.

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62485069/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had reinstalled the Nvidia driver: run these commands in *root* mode:

1. `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`
2. `modprobe -r nvidia-drm`
3. Reinstall the Nvidia driver: `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64–410.57.run`
4. `systemctl start graphical.target`

And finally check `nvidia-smi`

Thanks to:

- *[How To Install Nvidia Drivers and CUDA-10.0 for RTX 2080 Ti GPU on Ubuntu-16.04/18.04](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-and-cuda-10-0-for-rtx-2080-ti-gpu-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-ce32e4edf1c0)*
- *[How to unload kernel module 'nvidia-drm'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440840/how-to-unload-kernel-module-nvidia-drm)*

Answer (score 0):

I committed the container into a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) image. Then I recreated another container using this Docker image and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I ran into this issue as well. In my case it turned out that because I had set Clang as my default compiler (using `update-alternatives`), `nvidia-driver-440` failed to compile (check `/var/crash/`) even though `apt` didn't post any warnings. For me, the solution was to `apt purge nvidia-*`, set `cc` back to use `gcc`, reboot, and reinstall `nvidia-driver-440`.

Answer (score 0):

First I installed the Nvidia driver.

Next I installed CUDA.

After that, I got the "Driver/library version mismatch" *error*, but I could see the CUDA version, so I purged the Nvidia driver and reinstalled it.

Then it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution that worked for me. On [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 33, try the following:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i nvidia | grep f32
```

You should have two packages listed from the previous version of Fedora for [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL). Remove those and reboot.

Deleting and reinstalling the entire Nvidia package set is overkill.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem and I'm posting my solution here.

In my case, the NVRM version was *440.100* and the driver version was *460.32.03*. My driver was updated by `sudo apt install caffe-cuda` and I didn't notice at that time, but I checked it from `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

By following my NVRM version, I just used `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`, but it installed *450.102*. I don't know why it installed another version and *nvidia-smi* is showing *450.102.04*.

Anyhow, after rebooting my PC, everything is working fine now. After reinstalling the driver, still my CUDA is working fine.

I didn't **remove/purge** anything related to the Nvidia driver. Version *460.32.03* was uninstalled automatically by running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`.

Comment: Because the issue was closed, I can't post the solution here. But for me the fix was different. See here: stackoverflow.com/a/71672261/10554033