# nvidia-smi not working after installing driver in a singularity container

Tags: driver, nvidia, singularity-container

I use singularity and I need to install a nvidia driver in my singularity container to do some deep learning with a gtx 1080.
This singularity image is created from a nvidia docker from here:
https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:kaldi and converted to a singularity container.
There was no nvidia drivers I think because nvidia-smi was not found before I install the driver.

I did the following commmands :

```
    add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
    sudo apt update
    apt install nvidia-418
```

after that I wanted to see if the driver was well installed, I did the command :

```
nvidia-smi
```

which return : Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

I searched about how to solve this error and found this topic : 
[NVIDIA NVML Driver/library version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch)

One answer says to do the command :

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

and then to rmmod on each except nvidia and finally to rmmod nvidia.

```
rmmod drm
```

But when I do this, as the topic excepted it, I have the error :
rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use.

The topic says to tap lsof /dev/nvidia*, and to kill the process that use the module, but I see nothing with drm written, and it seems to be a very bad idea to kill the process (Xorg, gnome-she).

Here is the answer to the command lsof /dev/nvidia*, followed by the command lsmod | grep nvidia, and then rmmod drm [image]
Rebooting the computer also didn't work.

what should I do to manage using nvidia-smi and be able to use my GPU from inside the  singularity container ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your answer.
I wanted to install the GPU driver in the singularity container because when inside the container, I wasn't able to use the GPU (nvidia-smi : command not found) while outside of the container I could use nvidia-smi.

You are right, the driver should be installed outside of the container, I wanted to install it in the container to avoid my problem of not having access to the driver from inside the container.

Now I found the solution : To use GPU from inside the singularity container, you must add --nv when calling the container.
example :

```
singularity exec --nv singularity_container.simg ~/test_gpu.sh
```

or

```
singularity shell --nv singularity_container.simg
```

When you add --nv, the container will have access to the nvidia driver and nvidia-smi will work.
Without this you will not be able to use GPU, nvidia-smi will not work.

Comment: To clarify the above on Singularity 1.1.8, regardless of `--nv` the `/dev` virtual directory is mounted (i.e. nvidia0, nvidia1, nvidia2, nvidia3 and the mods nvidia-modeset, nvidiactl, nvidia-uvm which are unloaded in the non-reboot hack in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319156/4625475). With the `--nv` `/usr/lib/nvidia/` and `/usr/lib64/nvidia/` are mounted as `/.singularity.d/libs` and possible kernel modules somewhere whereas `/usr/local/cuda` (cuda toolkit) and `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi` are not —the latter can be bounded without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do the above steps in the host OS and not in the container itself. `/dev` is mounted into the container as is and still subject to use by the host, though the processes are run in a different userspace.