# CUDA initialization: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount()

Tags: python, linux, pytorch

I was running a deep learning program on my Linux server and I suddenly got this error.

`UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() that might have already set an error? Error 804: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1603729096996/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)`

Earlier when I just created this conda environment, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returned `true` and I could use CUDA & GPU. But all of a sudden I could not use CUDA and `torch.cuda.is_available()`returned `false`. What should I do?

ps. I use GeForce RTX 3080 and cuda 11.0 + pytorch 1.7.0. It worked before but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 44):

I just tried rebooting. Problem solved. Turned out that it was caused by NVIDIA NVML Driver/library version mismatch.

Comment: I have the same issue and it disappears consistently when I reboot. However, I would like not to have to reboot. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: maybe you can try some of the solutions in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch

Comment: for me it is not a problem of version mismatch, unfortunately.

Comment: Apt may not automatically change the kernel modules. You may be able to just `modprobe nvidia` to update the drivers in use.

Answer (score 12):

Try to run `nvidia-smi` in a different terminal and if you get an error like: `NVML: Driver/library version mismatch` then basically you have to follow these steps, so you won't have to reboot again:

1. In a terminal run: `lsmod | grep nvidia`.
2. Then unload the module dependent on nvidia driver:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
```

3. Finally, unload the nvidia module: `sudo rmmod nvidia`.
4. Now when you try `lsmod | grep nvidia`, you should get nothing in the terminal output.
5. Now run `nvidia-smi` to check if you get the desired output and you are good to go!

Comment: can you explain why this recipe resolves the issue?

Comment: NVML is an API directly linked to various parameters of your GPU hardware. And your nvidia driver has been built on your hardware. I suspect that when we direct install a pre-build version of any program to run like pytorch or cudatoolkit, it happens to not properly work for the build version install on the GPU. Cloning the version of pytorch and building it from scratch might be a solution but we don't take that much of hassle unless required. You know our code can work much faster if we build the pytorch in our  local machine!

Comment: I get this error when I run `sudo rmmod nvidia_drm`: `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia_drm is in use`

Comment: The answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022843/nvidia-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch provides a solution to my problem

Comment: What if `nvidia-smi` functions well?

Answer (score 6):

First check the nvidia-fabricmanager service status:

```
systemctl status nvidia-fabricmanager
```

If you see that the nvidia-fabricmanager service is in active (running) state, it is running properly, otherwise restart:

```
systemctl start nvidia-fabricmanager
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Let me reboot k8s node...

In my case problem was little complex, because it was not PC, but server with k8s and nvidia-container-toolkit. Toolkit is managing some of the nvidia/cuda libraries inside container. The key to check it was running command `ls -al /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libcuda` in working and not working containers. I think that output of command and linked cuda library version should match version of host.:

Working

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       12 Mar  8 15:15 libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       21 Mar  8 15:15 libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.525.147.05
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29867944 Oct 25 20:37 libcuda.so.525.147.05
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       29 Mar  8 15:15 libcudadebugger.so.1 -> libcudadebugger.so.525.147.05
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10490248 Oct 25 20:18 libcudadebugger.so.525.147.05
```

Not working

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        12 Mar  8 15:17 libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 Mar  8 15:17 libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.530.30.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29867944 Oct 25 20:37 libcuda.so.525.147.05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29900840 Feb 22  2023 libcuda.so.530.30.02
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Mar  8 15:17 libcudadebugger.so.1 -> libcudadebugger.so.530.30.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10490248 Oct 25 20:18 libcudadebugger.so.525.147.05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10488936 Feb 16  2023 libcudadebugger.so.530.30.02
```

Host:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.525.147.05
```

To fix the problem, one can simply change the `libcuda.so.1` link target from `libcuda.so.530.30.02` to `libcuda.so.525.147.05` in my situation. In your situations you may have different driver versions.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are having this issue after updaing your driver. You could try

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-fabricmanager-535`

to update library version. Replace the 535 with your driver version.

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience:

- I had a PyTorch 1.12, an Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080, `cuda/11.3.1`, and `cudnn/8.2.4.15-11.4` on my system, and I got `CUDA initialization error`.
- The error had been solved by only changing the `cudnn` version, i.e., I used `cudnn/8.2.0.53-11.3` and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

It can append. Try reinstalling a nvidia driver. Then reboot you computer (it's important), and check if nvidia-smi works.